# Update panel causes JavaScript error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, updatepanel

I am facing this issue in my asp.net application when using update panel. The error only with IE9 and for other browser application works fine. For debuging purpose and to conclude the issue only when using update panel I created a sample asp.net web site.

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Click Me" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button, I get the following JS error.

The JS error is

From IE's F12 developer tool,

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'tagName': object is null or undefined 
frameTracker.js, line 2 character 395
```

From Visual Studio 2012,

[image]

[image]

But when I remove the update panel, the JS error is no longer.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />
```

OR

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />
```

OR

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> // is will always be rendered in IE's latest and greatest mode
```

Comment: For your first option I get this error.
Unhandled exception at line 1, column 68 in http://static.freetwittube.com/apps/tv-classic/popup-bg.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'postMessage': object is null or undefined

And for the second, the error described in the question comes.

Comment: are you sure you are getting this exception after adding above code??

Comment: You should use first option provided by me and look for what `Unable to get value of the property 'postMessage': object is null or undefined` exception is coming because property 'postMessage' should be used somewhere else in your code

Comment: You can see my code that it is very simple and I do not use any script there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I have already tried this but no luck.